# make a background process listen to keyboard input

Tags: c, linux, background-process

So I'm making a chat program for the fun of it because I don't like the program write on our schools linux cluster. What I want it to do is once you run it once it goes to the background and you can check it from the command line to see if you have any new messages. So i was wondering if there is a way to have the background job listen to terminal input and if it is something it recognizes like "messages" or "chat" it would bring the job back to the foreground so you could reply. I know you can use fg then the PID of the process to bring it back but thats not very clean for users and just plain annoying for me.

Comment: It could send mail to the UNIX user

Comment: that is possible but i want something i have more control over and can add more options too a program that just takes your string and pipes it to mail is really just mail with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just have a messages_cmd (written in shell) which can just

```
pgrep chat_program_name
```

to get the pid and then bring it to the foreground.

Comment: but then you have to remember to use pgrep and the name of the program i want something like mail where you can just type mail and it will tell you if you have any new messages and you can respond to them.

Comment: @staticFlow instead of bringing back up the program just check whatever it writes messages to. For example if on receive of a message you store it in a database. You can just have a "read" column then when you type that it will go out check the database and return the messages you haven't read. If that suits your needs I will edit my answer.

Comment: but I don't want the process just throwing new messages up on their terminal screen, that's what's awful about write it just cuts into what ever you are doing. I want it to keep track of new messages but only show you them when you ask for them.